# How to display count(numbers) with every ArrayList item?

Tags: android

I want to display serial no. for each item, how can I do that?

```
for (int i = 1; i < pres.arrMedicine.size()-1; i++) {
    for (final MedicineModel medicine : prescription.arrMedicine) {
        ((TextView) dialogPrintPrescription
                .findViewById(R.id.txt_prescription)).append("\n " + i
                + ". "
                + medicine.getMedicineString());
    }
}
```

I was trying this to get serial no. Before every item which is going to be displayed.

Comment: And what is the error/non required behavior?

Comment: its displaying 1. , 1. , 1. with every item

Comment: sorry i dont know how to accept as using first time, so if you can help me in this too?

Comment: There would be a tick mark with black border below `0` on left sode of my answer. If not, it will come after sometime. You can click on that..!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need  for 2 `for` loops.
You can try this code:

```
int i = 1;
for (final MedicineModel medicine : prescription.arrMedicine) {
        ((TextView) dialogPrintPrescription
                .findViewById(R.id.txt_prescription)).append("\n " + i
                + ". "
                + medicine.getMedicineString());
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should transform your both arrays like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < pres.arrMedicine.size()-1; i++) {
    ((TextView) dialogPrintPrescription
          .findViewById(R.id.txt_prescription)).append("\n " + i
           + ". "
           + pres.arrMedicine.get(i).getMedicineString());
}
```

else the value of i never increase while iterating through the medicines

Answer (score 0):

The above mentioned answers are correct. In addition you can use the `indexOf(Object o)` method of the ArrayList Class. This avoids the use of an extra variable i.e.

```
for (final MedicineModel medicine : prescription.arrMedicine) {
    ((TextView) dialogPrintPrescription
            .findViewById(R.id.txt_prescription)).append(
                                   "\n " + prescription.arrMedicine.indexOf(medicine)
                                   + ". "
                                   + medicine.getMedicineString());
}
```

Hope this helps too !!